# Scroll text across screen in android

Tags: android

I am trying to make long piece of text scroll across the screen, I have come across this piece of code, and however the entire text scrolls across the screen rather than scrolling in a single line. So how can I make it scroll in straight line?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView txtscroll;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.scrollable_contents);
    txtscroll = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtscrol);

    Animation translatebu = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            R.anim.animationfile);
    txtscroll.setText("Some text view.");
    txtscroll.startAnimation(translatebu);

    ScrollView scrollable_contents = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollableContents);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.contents, scrollable_contents);

}
```

}

```
<translate
    android:duration="5000"
    android:fromXDelta="100%p"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:toXDelta="-100%p" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use substring and display it in a single line, you need a timer for this.